# How to make the following emphasis in other tenses: "I did read it yesterday" and "I do read it every day"

Tags: sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs, emphasis

As you know we can make emphasis in the simple present and past tense by using the auxiliary in the following way:

"I read newspapers everyday to keep myself updated" can be used "**I do read newspapers every day**...."

And as far as I know, we can do this only for sentences which are structured in the **simple present tense and simple past tense**. For instance, in simple past tense, it would be: **"I did read newspapers yesterday."**

However, if we want to make the same emphasis in other tenses, how can we do it? how can we make the same emphasis in other tenses (**future, perfect and continuous tenses)**?

For instance we can't say **"I will will read newspapers tomorrow"** nor **"I was was reading newspapers"** nor "**I am am reading newspapers",** but there must definitely be a way to produce the same emphasis in writing in the tenses other than simple present and simple past.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using the verb "do" as an auxiliary to add emphasis to the already affirmative statement "I read newspapers every day", you would emphasise the word in speech, and possibly in written form using italics:

> I *do* read newspapers every day.

The most common use of the verb this way for adding emphasis is to either contradict a previous statement or in response to a suggestion to do something by showing that it is already the case, for example:

> -Why don't you read newspapers?
>   -I *do* read newspapers. (contradict)
>
> -You should read newspapers.
>   -I *do* read newspapers (confirming)

If you made the statement unprompted it would sound strange with the auxiliary verb.

---

In the *future tense*, I should point out the obvious and say that if you tell someone "I read newspapers every day" that would include tomorrow. But if you want to speak *only* about a time in the future, you would use "will". You can't use the word twice as you pointed out, so if you want to add emphasis you could either:

1. Verbally emphasise or italicise the verb *will*:

   - I *will* read the newspapers tomorrow.
2. Use an adverb:

   - I will **definitely** read the newspapers tomorrow.
   - I **certainly** will read the newspapers tomorrow.

---

You likely know that the past tense of "do" is "*did*". You don't need it, as you could just say "I read the newspapers yesterday", but if you need to add emphasis then either use "did", or some other adverb, or both:

- I *did* read the newspapers yesterday.
- I definitely read the newspapers yesterday.
- I definitely did read the newspapers yesterday.